# python: как с помощью numpy добавить в начало массива колонку с заданным значением

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Подскажите, как с помощью `numpy` в питоне можно колонку заданному массиву

Например, есть массив

```
1, 2
3, 4
5, 6
7, 8
```

И надо чтобы получился массив

```
10, 1, 2
10, 3, 4
10, 5, 6
10, 7, 8
```

Не хотелось бы делать в лоб обычными средствами через создание нового массива и добавление строк по одной

Answer (score 4):

все, разобрался

```
data = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8])
data = np.insert(data, 0, 10, axis=1)
```

Comment: Можно ещё через `np.hstack`, но так даже короче, не знал )